# Capture content of possible capture group

Tags: regex

I want to get the content of a html control using regex.  There is a possible occurrence of a string, and if it occurs i wants to capture it's content.

I tried using this pattern:

```
<img src="data:image.*base64,(?<base64>.+)".*alt="(?<alt>.+)".*/>
```

But this does not return any results when there is no alt present in my content (which is possible)

I then tried:

```
<img src="data:image.*base64,(?<base64>.+)".*(alt=".+")?.*/>
```

This return my first caputure group whether alt is present or not, but it does not contain a second capture group for the contents of the alt
I tried combining the 2, but this does not what i want at all:

```
<img src="data:image.*base64,(?<base64>.+)".*(alt="(?<alt>.+)")?.*/>
```

This return an empty capture group which is not right at all.

Example of the content I am trying to match:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" alt="blabla" />
```

The output should return me the base54 string in the base64 capture group (working) and should return the blabla in the second capture group (named alt).  It should continue to work whether or not alt is present in the string.  If it's not present it's okay if the capture group alt is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img src="data:image.*?;base64,(?<base64>.+?)"(?: alt="(?<alt>.+)" )?\/>`

You're pretty close with your implementation! If you surround your "alt" group with a non-capturing group and make it optional with `?`, then the capture group won't return an empty match if nothing is present. Your other capture group should work regardless.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/OsfCbP/1)

Comment: Thanks, marking as non capturing group is the ?: part?
I already tried adding the ? at the end to make it optional, i knew about that but didn't seem to get it to work

Comment: @ThierryVerhaegen That's correct, `(?:  )` is a non capturing group. Your second regex isn't working because it has the greedy quantifier `.*` before the optional capture group: this made the regex eat all of the alt text before the capture group had a chance to get to it, and since the capture group was optional, the engine just ignored that group altogether and didn't try to force it to match.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :-)